# Tkinter widgets not showing on mac (using PyCharm and Terminal)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am using python 3.9 (and have also tried my code with Python 3.10 in terminal) on a mac (OS High Sierra) and my IDE is PyCharm. No Widgets I have tried with tkinter are showing up. Here I am using Label but I have also used Entry too - i just get a blank window:[image]

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


class View:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title("Play Suduko")
        self.root.grid()
        self.form = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding=10)

        self.model = model
        self.S = self.model.S

        for self.i, self.row in enumerate(self.S):
            for self.j, self.element in enumerate(self.row):
                if self.element != 0:
                    self.label = ttk.Label(self.form, text=str(self.element))
                    self.label.grid(row=self.i, column=self.j)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty sure it's not the IDE because as I said I tried it in the Terminal with Python 3.10 and got the same thing.

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:

I updated my code to remove form. So here is the new code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class View(Frame):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Play Suduko")
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.model = model
        self.S = self.model.S
        for self.i, self.row in enumerate(self.S):
            for self.j, self.element in enumerate(self.row):
                if self.element != 0:
                    self.label = Label(self.root, textvariable=str(self.element), width=2)
                    self.label.grid(row=self.i, column=self.j, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

And this is the window I am seeing now:

[image]

Comment: you didn't put `self.form` on `self.root` (it's done with `pack`, `grid` or `place` methods (and do it in a new line)), also `self.root.grid()` is definitely not something you need to do

Comment: @Matiiss Ahh sorry, new to this. I followed the Hello World program here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html  What do you mean 'put self.form on self.root'?

Comment: I mean that you need to use one of `pack`, `grid` or `place` (in most cases it is not used) with `self.form`, so after defining `self.form`, use `self.form.pack()` for example (or any of the other methods listed above)

Comment: @Matiiss okay, i tried adding self.form.grid(rowspan=100, columnspan=100) and I still can't see my Label widget, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: the `rowspan` and `columnspan` would refer to `self.root`'s grid so in this example they seem not necessary, could you [edit] the question and add the current code with how you gridded the frame?

Comment: @Matiiss okay, edited :)

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question. If you have an answer, write it as an answer instead.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class View(Frame):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Play Suduko")
        Frame.__init__(self, self.root)

        self.model = model
        self.S = self.model.S
        for self.i, self.row in enumerate(self.S):
            for self.j, self.element in enumerate(self.row):
                if self.element == 0:
                    self.element = ""
                self.label = Label(self.root, text=str(self.element), width=2, font=("Arial", 40))
                self.label.grid(row=self.i, column=self.j+1, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

:)

Comment: This answer could be improved. Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what was wrong, and how that problem was fixed. See [answer] and the [help] for more information on writing good answers. Also, please don't post the answer in the question.

Comment: The Label should say text not textvariable and the frame needed the root passed to it. Not sure why passing frame to view fixed it, but this method worked for me.

Comment: You aren't passing `Frame` to `View` in this case; you are making `View` a child of `Frame`. Also, did you see the part about _editing your **answer**_? That means that you should put the explanation _in the answer_ instead of in the comments. I stated that very clearly in my previous comment. If you click on this [edit] link, it should take you to a page where you can edit your answer. You also didn't seem to notice the part about _not putting the answer in the question_. Also, did you read the [answer] link I gave you? It _will_ help you keep from making mistakes like this in the future.